# MySQL tune slow delete

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm using `MySQL InnoDB`, one of the most important tables has over 700 million records with totally 23 actively used indexes.

I am trying to delete the records in a batch of 2000 based on the record date (and order by on primary key column). Each date has around 6 million records, I delete it date by date with `limit` 2000. Each batch takes around 25 seconds to complete. Since it is a Production database, I want this delete operation to complete faster. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: How does deleting date by date work in batches of 2000 if each date has 6 million rows?

Comment: @BillKarwin with a Limit clause.

Comment: No, use a precomputed range on the `PRIMARY KEY`.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig .

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide DELETE improving suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

There are many solutions.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig .

Which takes 25 seconds?  A batch of 2000 rows?  Or several of those?  Are they in a single, big, transaction?  Lots of little transactions would be slower, but less invasive.  And there would be no ACID problem since re-deleting the same 'date' should be idempotent.

If the table is "locked" at some level for 25 seconds, then I understand your concern.  If it is a bunch of sub-second deletes, then does it really matter that it takes a long time?

Furthermore, instead of deleting once a day, you could delete once an hour.  This might decrease the tasks to 2 seconds instead of 25.

25 indexes is terribly large.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  It is all too common that there are "redundant" indexes that could (should) be dropped.  The main example is `INDEX(a,b)` takes care of `INDEX(a)` (but not `b`), so if you have both, drop the latter.

It may be impractical to make the change now, but `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(...))` lets you `DROP PARTITION`, which is virtually instantaneous.  (Adding partitioning to a 700M row table would take a long time.)

Comment: I have checked all the indexes and there is no redundant or duplicate index. The table has ~ 50 columns. The total index size occupied by the table is ~500gb and the table size is almost a TB.

Comment: Please provide the `SHOW` anyway.  And RAM size and `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.